# Floating-point for ARM in Visual C++

Tags: c++, arm, visual-foxpro

I'm using Visual C++ 2005 for building applications for ARM, Qualcomm Snapdragon chip. I know it supports VFPv3. Where can I get SDK or something like to use floating-point arithmetics hardware? Best of all if Visual C++ compiler would generate VFP instructions instread of emulating.

Comment: if you have bad luck you have to resort to inline asm instructions...

Answer (score 1):

Try `/QRfpe-` compiler option. It will [Enable Hardware Floating Point Targeting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552256.aspx). But I don't know, is it present in VS2005 - the document is about VS 2008 compiler.
And I'm not sure VFPv3 is supported. Maybe it supports some earlier VFP version.

Other way is to use different compiler, e.g. [RealView ARM Compiler](http://www.arm.com/products/DevTools/RVCT.html) and it's optimized libs.